# Не меняется lable длительности и названия трека

Tags: ios, objective-c

Я новичек в iOS программировании, не могу понять как решить данную проблему. Я программирую плеер, с помощью метода:

```
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag{

if (!flag){
    NSLog(@"ERROR");}


[_audioPlayer stop];
[self nextSong];
[self curTime];
}
```

я определяю закончился ли данный трек и воспроизвожу следующий. Но при этом label с названием трека и label с его длительность не изменяются(при нажатии кнопок nextSong/prevSong все хорошо). Подскажите как это исправить?

Answer (score 2):

Возможно, обновление UI не в главном потоке. Надо поставить брейкпоинт в месте изменения длительности и названия - убедится, в каком потоке происходит вызов. Заодно, убедиться, что там приходят новые данные.

Если не в главном потоке:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    //  Обновление UI
});
```

Comment: Почему вы так считаете?

Comment: Если вы будете пытаться менять название у label не в главном потоке, то ничего не будет меняться. dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        /// update UI
    });

Comment: Не надо писать комментариев. Под вашим сообщением есть кнопка править, дополните ответ.

Comment: То есть, не нужно было отвечать на комментарии? Я не собирался в ответ ничего дописывать.

Comment: Нет, не нужно. Доподните ваш  ответ.